# Any explanation of the following?(Intervals , diameter of a set)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

If an the following interval is defined as : $$I^n=(x_1,x_1+\delta)\times (x_2,x_2+\delta)\dots \times(x_n,x_n+\delta)$$ then the $diamI^n=\delta\sqrt n$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval $I^n$ is an n-dimensional hypercube with edge length $\delta$. The function $diam$ measures the largest distance between two Corners in this hypercube. For example, in a square it holds that the longest distance between two Corners is given by: $\sqrt{2} \delta$ because $2 \delta^2 = \delta^2+\delta^2 = (diam I^2)^2$. Analogously, in 3 dimensions one has to go through three edges until the Corner which has the Maximum distance is reached. Hence: $(diam I^3)^2= \delta^2 + \delta^2 + \delta^2$. In $n$ dimensions there must be traversed $n$ edges from an arbitrary Corner of the hypercube to the Corner which has Maximum distance to the initial Corner.

$(diamI^n)^2=n \delta^2$ (traversing edges $n$ times)

Answer (score 1):

There are various definitions of diameter.

Here you seem to be using
$\operatorname{diam} A = \sup_{x,y \in A} \|x-y\|$.

It is easy to see that if $x,y \in I^n$, then $|x_i-y_i| < \delta$, so
$\|x-y\| \le \sqrt{n} \delta$, and so
$\operatorname{diam} I^n \le \sqrt{n} \delta$.

By choosing $x=(x_1+\epsilon, ..., x_n+\epsilon)$,
$y=(y_1+\delta-\epsilon, ..., y_n+\delta-\epsilon)$ for suitably small $\epsilon>0$ we have $x,y \in A$ and
$\|x-y\| = \sqrt{n} (\delta-2 \epsilon)$. Hence we have
$\operatorname{diam} I^n =\sqrt{n} \delta$.